# How to use the HTML Helper of Listbox?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to create a simple Listbox, utilising HTML Helpers and I can't find any resource that guides me through this.

```
<%= Html.ListBox("listbox_name") %>
```

And it asks for `IEnumerable(SelectListItem)` and I dont know how to create one and pass it.

Please help me

Comment: do you using asp.net webforms or MVC ?

Comment: @harry180 Notice he has tagged the question as html-helper so it is MVC

Comment: @harry180, Yes, I use `mvc-2`

Comment: Did you  try anything? in code behind you can make method which will `return` `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`I'm not really pro in mvc so I don't know how it should be done in this html-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you want to provide the data for the listbox. If it is static data, you could simply declare a `List<SelectListItem>` in the view and pass that in:

```
var mySelectItems = new List<SelectListItem> { 
    new SelectListItem { Text = "First item", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Second item", Value = "2" }
};
...
Html.ListBox("listbox_name", mySelectItems)
```

Otherwise, just get the data from whereever you get it, and pass it in with the model

Comment: Never written VB.net, but a quick search indicates it would be something like `Dim mySelectItems = New List(Of SelectListItem) From { New SelectListItem With {.Text = "First item", .Value = "1" } }`. (Works in LINQPad, at least, so now I've officially written my first VB.Net!)

Comment: That worked, what do i need to change to work with DropDownList

Comment: `Html.Dropdown` should be enough. Might be a good time to read the documentation, too - these things are fairly well explained.

Comment: Also, there is a method called Html.DropDownList, the method should work similar to ListBox, but I am getting weird problem. `Override resolution failed...`